# SBT. Выполнить jar внутри таски

Tags: scala, sbt

Есть простой проект:
[image: Структура проекта]

Внутри `lib` лежит собранный `my.jar`.
Есть таска внутри `build.sbt`:

```
TaskKey[Unit]("myTask") := {
    // Тут выполняются некоторые действия

    // После выполнения некоторых действий, 
    // необходимо выполнить my.jar с некоторыми аргументами,
    // скажем -a1 argument1 -a2 argument2 
}
```

Как выполнить `my.jar` в теле таски, передав аргументы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение было найдено [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432636/how-to-run-jar-inside-sbt-task/45432936#45432936)

```
TaskKey[Unit]("myTask") := {
  Process(Seq("java", "-jar", "my.jar", "-a1", "argument", "-a2", "argument"),
    (baseDirectory.value / "lib")).!
}
```